# How to use Retrofit Cache in the following source code?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am not able to use retrofit caching. I have searched the forum many times, most of the result is okay and I am able to find the concept of it but when I tried to implement in the code I am not able to do so. Please help me as I am also new to retrofit. One week I tried to use volley library and everything was okay  with the cache but volley send two requests and my data are displaying two times, I tried every possible way but unable to do so with volley and finally now I shifted to retrofit but here again I am stuck as I am not from computer science background. Please help me I will be thankful to everyone. I want to use retrofit with these following code only. These Sample Codes are taken from https://github.com/prakashpun/RetrofitTutorial

**RetrofitClientInstance.java**

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**GetDataService.java**

```
public interface GetDataService {
@GET("/photos")
Call<List<RetroPhoto>> getAllPhotos();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);

        Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call = service.getAllPhotos();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RetroPhoto>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Response<List<RetroPhoto>> response) {

                generateDataList(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void generateDataList(List<RetroPhoto> photoList) {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.customRecyclerView);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,photoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**Sample of these part where I will implement in the Above Codes and how to do it.**

```
Cache cache = new Cache(getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(cache)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain)
                        throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale \
                        request = request
                                .newBuilder()
                                .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                                .build();
                    }
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            })
            .build();
```

Comment: I think this part is done with help of interceptor and you are not using that.

Comment: yes, i know but i am unable to do so, i am trying from many days but not able to implement it in the codes, please help me.How to do it. I will be very much thankful to you, i am very much frustrated.

Comment: @KatrinaPathak have you tried [this](https://medium.com/@arthur_sav/auto-caching-with-retrofit-9384c00d52be).

Comment: Yes i have tried but i am unable to implement in the following code ,as i am very beginner in android and learning everything of my own and also i am not from a computer science background.Please help me where and how to implement in the above sample source code.

Comment: Sorry I have gone somewhere, have you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
        .cache(cache)
        .build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but where to implement it. As i am not from a computer science background and what ever i have learned till now of my own ,so here now i am stuck.

Comment: RetrofitClientInstance In this class

Answer (score 0):

You can use cache mechanism using intercepter from okhttp,
Here I found one best implementation documentation with the example which will maybe help you

https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-1-network-error-handling-response-caching-77483cf68620

Here is the small code snippet

```
public class AppliCationClass extends Application {

  public static final int DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB

  private OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okhttpClientBuilder.cache(getCache());
    return okhttpClientBuilder.build();
  }

  public Cache getCache() {
      File cacheDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "cache");
      Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDir, DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
      return cache;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, i will try it from the link that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

For some cloud API's caching can be useful and please refer below link for more information.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified

In summary below are the steps

## 1) Initialize Cache

```
int cacheSize = SIZE_MB * 1024 * 1024; // Size in mb
Cache cache = new Cache(getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
```

## 2) Use OkHttpClient cache feature

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
    .cache(cache)
    .build();
```

## 3) Use above http client to build Retrofit

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl("http://www.your_api_base_url.in/")
    .client(okHttpClient);

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am checked this but unable to do so in the above code.Really i am frustrated.Anyway thank you for replying.

Comment: Also, please try to write code with some architecture in mind, like do not use Retrofit directly inside Activity. Create different modules for UI, persistence, networking, trust me that would be really helpful.

Comment: okay i will keep it in mind and try to figure it out.But as i very new so i am stuck. It is really a helpful forum,everything i have learned from stackoverflow and now everyone are replying it very fast and also this is my first question. With all the replies and finding the concept to implement me, it will take time.Hope i am able to so. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this function

```java
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB  
Cache cache = new Cache(getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
        .cache(cache)
        .build();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, i will try this.

Comment: Sir, i have tried unable to do so actually where i will implement it unable to find it. showing me Cache( ) 
in Cache cannot be applied
to
(java.io.File,
int)
I have put the code above getServiceData in MainActivity.java